# R data table select entry with largest sum

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with 3 columns: Field1, Field2 and Value.
For each attribute in Field2, I want to find the attribute in Field1 that corresponds to the largest sum of Value (ie there are multiple Field1 / Field2 rows in the data table).

When I try this: `x[,.(Field1 = Field1[which.max(sum(Value))]),.(Field2)]` I seem to be getting the first Field1 row for each Field2 rather than the row corresponding to the max sum of Value.

As an extension, what if you wanted to provide both the sum of value, the total number of rows and the Field1 value corresponding to the largest sum across the Value field within Field2?

Below is a reproducible code.

```
library(data.table)

#Set random seed
set.seed(2017)

#Create a table with the attributes we need
x = data.table(rbind(data.frame(Field1 = 1:12,Field2 = rep(1:3, each = 4), Value = runif(12)),
               data.frame(Field1 = 1:12,Field2 = rep(1:3, each = 4), Value = runif(12))))

#Let's order by Field2/ Field1 / Value
x = x[order(Field2,Field1,Value)]

#Check
print(x)

# This works, but requires 2 steps which can complicate things when needing 
# to pull other attributes too.
(x[,.(Value = sum(Value)),.(Field2,Field1)][,.SD[which.max(Value)],.(Field2)])

#This instead provides the row corresponding to the largest Value.
(x[,.(Field1 = Field1[which.max(Value)]),.(Field2)])

# This is what I was ideally looking for but it only returns the first row of the attribute 
# regardless of the value of Value, or the corresponding sum.
(x[,.(Field1 = Field1[which.max(sum(Value))]),.(Field2)])

# This works but seems clumsy

(x[, 
.SD[, .(RKCNT=length(.I),TotalValue=sum(Value)), .(Field1)]
[,.(RKCNT = sum(RKCNT), TotalValue = sum(TotalValue), 
Field1 = Field1[which.max(TotalValue)])], 
.(Field2)])
```

Comment: Assuming there are no ties, you could sort by the sum and then use `unique`: `x[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(Field2, Field1)][order(Field2, -Value), unique(.SD, by="Field2")]`. I'm guessing there's a dupe of this question somewhere.

Comment: Not your main question, but FYI the data.table idiom for ordering is to use `setorder` "Fast row reordering of a data.table by reference"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
x[, .SD[, sum(Value), Field1][which.max(V1)], Field2]
```

Which is concise and thus somewhat easier to read. But does not give any performance improvement.